# definition of Russian word

Tags: одним-словом

what does саморазмораживающийся mean?

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! We do not forbid translation requests but note that **this is not a translation service**, so we will close any translation request that does not show research effort, as per the [FAQ]. You must make sure you clearly show it in your question if you want to avoid it. Note that you can edit your question and improve it by using the "edit" button below it. When you're done, flag it for moderator attention and we'll reopen it. Note: the -1 is automatic.

Answer (score 4):

"self-defrosting" as adjective (само+раз+моражив...), presumably as in "саморазмораживающийся холодильник"